# Is there a way to mix a iron golem farm and a villager (breeding) farm?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

With a villager farm, you get villager numbers that grow exponentially and iron golems spawn as a result. Isn't it optimal to make a villager farm and put an iron golem farm next to it so that we can have the most efficient rates of iron golem spawns also?

If so, what is the best way to do this in 1.2.5?

Comment: That is one of the best way to farm golems. I didn't try but read lot of things about it on internet. If you find a solution, let me know ^^

Comment: Can you provide a pointer to a villager farm?  The short answer is, "yes it is optimal" but how?  Not sure on that.  Yet.

Comment: @John, What do you mean by "pointer"?

Comment: @Jeffrey URL?  Blog entry?  Youtube video?  Some description of how to create a village breeding farm.

Comment: @John, http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sXfgUXuV6ac second video from "villagers breeding 1.2.5" search on youtube

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to constantly produce villagers in order to have an effective iron golem farm. Two basic conditions need to be in place for an iron golem to spawn:

1. **Villagers:** Iron golems spawn if there are at least *16* villagers nearby. For every 15 total villagers, one iron golem may spawn (16 = 1 golem, 32 = 2 golems, 48 = 3 golems, etc.)
2. **Houses:** It takes at least *21 houses* to spawn an iron golem. A "house" in Minecraft has a complicated definition; here's the simplified version on the Minecraft Forum:

> A block counts as being part of the "roof" when it is within 5 blocks of the door (in the two directions the door faces), its topside is exposed to sunlight during the day, and its bottom side is higher than the door's bottom side. Notice that a door is not a "house" without a roof, or with equal amount of roof on both sides.

That description is slightly misleading as the algorithm is more complicated. For more information, I recommend reading **Marfagames**' [thread](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/1071744-123-villager-help-for-breeding-houses-golems-wander-off-aso/) on the Minecraft Forum.

Generally speaking, with both those conditions satisfied, iron golems will spawn. I encourage you to read up on the specifics if you wish to design your own farm. Lower down I also recommend a specific design.

**Farming Tips**

- Having more than a greater number of villagers **will not** affect the rate at which iron golems spawn. The number of villagers only determines the iron golem cap.
- If you drop the iron golems at least 5 blocks down from your farm, they will no longer contribute toward the iron golem cap, and more will continue to spawn.
- A house only becomes part of a village if there is a villager within 16 blocks horizontally and 4 blocks vertically.

**More Resources**

- **JL2579** over on YouTube has made several [videos](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T5hGLUrzWIs) on iron golem farming, and has designed the most effective golem farm I've ever encountered.
- **Micromancero** came up with a farm design that inspirqed JL2579 (on YouTube).
- **Docm77** has done a lot of work with JL2579's farm on YouTube.

***Note***: I would love to post more links, but I don't have enough reputation. JL2579, Micromancero and Docm77's videos can be found easily via YouTube search.

Comment: I didn't catch this: "If you drop the iron golems at least 5 blocks down from your farm, they will no longer contribute toward the iron golem cap, and more will continue to spawn." could you explain it in other words?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't word that very well. When Minecraft searches for nearby iron golems, to determine whether it can spawn a new one, it  does not check lower than 4 blocks below the village. If an iron golem is 5 blocks below your lowest house, it will not contribute toward the iron golem limit.

Comment: @rpedroso That forums post was written in the days of 1.2.3.  In 1.2.5 golem spawning has changed.  Has the definition of house changed as well?  Or, in other words, does that description still apply?

Comment: @John As far as I can tell, the only changes to villagers from 1.2.3 to 1.2.5 was an improvement in villager door detection (which was causing people to get horrendous villager numbers). The definition of a "house" has not changed. Designs I used in 1.2.3 still work even in the 1.3 snapshots.